# How do you reverse the audio channels on a line-in cable on windows 10?

Tags: audio

Windows 10, I checked the line-in cable with my laptop, as well as the line-in port, it's the hardware's fault (a HDMI audio splitter), tested with my earbuds.

I'm not going to buy a new splitter right off the bat, so I want to know if there is a simple program or driver that can reverse the channels on an input.

On google most of the answers are terminated with "turn your speakers around" or there does not seem to be any answers at all.

Comment: You might consider Equalizer APO: https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by installing https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/ (thanks, Justin Pearce), and cross-copying the stereo channels